# ACTIONSCRIPT 2: Execute action once after pressing a Key

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I am making my first platform game on ADOBE FLASH CS6 with ActionScript 2. 
When I press <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> my character does a dash-attack animation.

> My problem is

If I don't hold <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>, the animation cuts. and if I hold it, my character keeps advancing forward.

> What I'd like is,

When I press and hold <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> I want my character to dash only once and execute the full animation. When the animation is done, if I'm still holding the correct inputs, I'd like my character to execute what I described earlier.

I managed to do a double jump correctly but I just can't think of a solution to my current problem. Any solutions?

Here's a link to my demo (There's a background music): http://www.fastswf.com/tLr3bCA

Inputs:

- <kbd>↑</kbd>(JUMP)
- <kbd>↓</kbd>(CROUCH)
- <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>(MOVE)
- HOLD <kbd>Q</kbd>(RUN FASTER)
- <kbd>SPACE</kbd> WHILE OFFGROUND (DOUBLE JUMP)
- <kbd>↓</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (SWIFT STRIKE) **<- issue**

Here is a part of the ActionScript s inside my character MovieClip (not on a frame timeline):

```
{
    //GENJI COMMANDS
    if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT) && !Key.isDown(81))
    {
        _x += speed;
        this.gotoAndStop("genjirun");
        this._xscale = 100;
    }
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT) && Key.isDown(81))
    {
        _x += speed + 5;
        this.gotoAndStop("genjirunfast");
        this._xscale = 100;
    }
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT) && !Key.isDown(81))
    {
        _x -= speed;
        this.gotoAndStop("genjirun");
        this._xscale = -100;
    }
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT) && Key.isDown(81))
    {
        _x -= speed + 5;
        this.gotoAndStop("genjirunfast");
        this._xscale = -100;
    }
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN) && touchingGround && !Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT) && !Key.isDown(Key.LEFT) && !Key.isDown(87))
    {
        this.gotoAndStop("genjicrouch");
    }
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN) && touchingGround && !Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT) && !Key.isDown(Key.LEFT) && Key.isDown(87) && _xscale == 100)
    {
        this.gotoAndStop("genjislash");
        _x += 5;


    }
    else if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN) && touchingGround && !Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT) && !Key.isDown(Key.LEFT) && Key.isDown(87) && _xscale == -100)
    {


        this.gotoAndStop("genjislash");
        _x += -5;



    }



    if (Key.isDown(Key.UP) && touchingGround)
    {
        grav = maxJump;
    }
    else if (!touchingGround && Key.isDown(32) && DJcancel == 0)
    {
        grav = -19;
        DJcancel = 3;
    }
    else if (!touchingGround or !Doublejumping == 3)
    {
        this.gotoAndStop("genjijump");
    }
    else if (touchingGround && !Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT) && !Key.isDown(Key.LEFT) && !Key.isDown(Key.DOWN))
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(1);
        DJcancel = 0;
    }
    if (touchingGround)
    {
        DJcancel = 0;
    }
```

Any suggestions? Also, is this method good or should I change it?

Answer (score 0):

First, I advise you to switch to AS3 because AS2 is 10 years as obsolete, and that is not without a reason. It is slow, very unstraight, and gives you a lot of wrong ideas. Also, there's nothing you cannot do with AS3 you could with AS2, but it is not the other way around: there are lots of things in AS3 you cannot do with AS2.

Also, I doubt there are any people out there who could professionally help you with AS2 exactly because it is 10 years since obsolete and is supported by Adobe for backward compatibility reasons only.

Then, your problem can be easily solved with a bit of logic. You need the [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) model. Lets define two state variables:

```
var dashKeys:Boolean = false;
var dashState:String = "none";
```

Variable **dashKeys** should represent <kbd>↓</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> pressed status. I believe you'll manage that with no problem. Variable **dashState** should take 3 distinct values (well, states): "*dash*" while dash animation is played, "*after*" if dash animation is complete and "*none*" if it is none of them. It obviously starts with "*none*".

Now, the logic.

```
if (dashState == "none")
{
    if (dashKeys)
    {
        // Switch to the next state.
        dashState = "dash";

        // Start the dash animation here.
    }
}
else if (dashState == "after")
{
    if (dashKeys)
    {
        // Do whatever you want your character to do after
        // dash animation if the keys are still pressed.
    }
    else
    {
        // Switch to the next state.
        dashState = "none";
    }
}
```

Now there only two things left.

1. Update **dashState** to "*after*" upon the dash animation complete, so the logic could advance.
2. Reset **dashState** to "*none*" if there are any cases you break the dash animation before it is complete in order to not stall the logic flow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I'll give it a shot as soon as I can. I will also switch to AS3.

Answer (score 0):

With AS2, define `.onKeyDown` for your MovieClip like this:

```
yourMC.onKeyDown = function(e) {
    // Now test e
};
```

It will be processed only once at the moment the key is pressed down, but won't be processed repeatedly if the key is held down.